# Google caliper -XX:CICompilerCount=2 vmOption does not apply

Tags: jvm, benchmarking, caliper

It's a known bug that since one of the build from Java 8 Tiered Compiler is turned on by default. And running benchmark without `@VmOptions({"-XX:-TieredCompilation"})` will cause below error:

> [stderr] CICompilerCount of 1 is invalid; must be at least 2

Turning off TieredCompilation is not desirable in benchmark. I tried adding `@VmOptions({":CICompilerCount=2"})`. But error "CICompilerCount of 1" persists.

Please advise how do I work this around without having to reset tiered compilation?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) over Caliper - see the related [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U). Otherwise turning off TieredCompilation is not bad at all comparing to other side effects Caliper sometimes demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to JMH. Clear better developer experience there.